# Is overloading a database object a bad practice?

Tags: php

I created the below class as a convenient way to create instances of `PDO` that I then inject into the classes that need access to my database. Instead of doing `$this->db->pdo` in subsequent classes, I overloaded the call method, but I've been reading in some posts that it's a bad practice. Would it be better to just create a static method that returns PDO that I then inject into my classes or another better way of doing this? (Is there some kinda of design pattern similar to this?) Thanks.

```php
<?php

namespace ShipExplorer\Database;

use PDO;

class Database
{

    protected $pdo;

    function __construct($config = ['host' => 'localhost', 'user' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'dbname' => ''], $pdoOptions = [])
    {

        $dsn = "mysql:host={$config['host']};dbname={$config['dbname']}";
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $config['user'], $config['password'], $pdoOptions);
    }


    function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $result = $this->pdo->$name(...$arguments);

        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to be careful here and stick to objective arguments.

Let's first get one thing out of the way. Many people argue that PDO is a complete database class in itself that doesn't need another class to make it accessible. I understand their point, but I don't fully agree with it. Sometimes it can be useful to add something to the PDO class. However, if you do, you better have a good reason for it.

#### More about overloading

- Overloading makes your code more difficult to understand, especially in more complicated cases. I admit that in your case this is not a real problem.
- People who use an [Integrated Development Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (IDE) often find that the tools, which help them write code, don't work well with overloading.
- You don't check, in `__call()`, whether a method exists, which means you can get errors that are more difficult to debug.

#### Is overloading really needed here?

Overloading is not really needed here. You can use a more standard feature of OOP: [Extending](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.extending.php). Using this in your class would give:

```
<?php

namespace StarExplorer\Database;

use PDO;

class Database extends PDO
{

    function __construct($config = ['host' => 'localhost', 'user' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'dbname' => ''], $pdoOptions = [])
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:host={$config['host']};dbname={$config['dbname']}";
        parent::__construct($dsn, $config['user'], $config['password'], $pdoOptions);
    }

}
```

This is something IDEs can cope with. It is functionally the same as your code but simpler. This code is therefore easier to understand and, if a bug occurs, it is usually easier to trace the problem. So, in this case I would advice against the use of overloading since it clearly has its disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

While we're at it, I'd suggest some improvements for the code, most of which are featured in the [article](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#Extending) I wrote some time ago, while others will utilize the most recent additions to PHP which I encourage you to try.

```
class Database extends PDO
{
    public function __construct(
        $host = 'localhost', 
        $user = 'root', 
        #[\SensitiveParameter] $password = '', 
        $dbname = 'test', 
        $options = [],
    ) {
        $default_options = [
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        ];
        $options = array_replace($default_options, $options);
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8mb4";
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
    }
    public function run($sql, $args = NULL)
    {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
$db = new Database(dbname: 'test');
$user = $db->run("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?", [$id])->fetch();
```

What is done here?

1. You don't need that `$config` variable anymore. PHP supports named parameters, which means you already can provide only values that differ from default ones, without using that extra variable.
2. The `$password` parameter is marked as *sensitive* so its value wouldn't appear in the stack trace.
3. Some useful PDO parameters are enabled by default. While the other two are rather arbitrary but `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is a MUST.
4. Yet some of them can be overridden by ones provided in the `$options` array
5. Charset is added to DSN which is quite important.
6. An extremely useful `run()` method is added to do that boring chore of prepare/bind/execute in one go.